# Labeling alternating max/mins based on a user defined delta

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Given a set of values (points on a graph) find all the max/min points such that

- there is no max is followed by a max (i.e. the max and min points alternate)
- there is some minimum amount of change (`C`) between each max and min (.4 for this data set)
- the value of the minimums must be lower than the adjacent maximums

Here is what I have so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MAX = 1
MIN = -1
NEITHER = 0

def normalize(a):
    #this function is for graphing purposes

    min_ = min(a)
    max_ = max(a)
    d = max_ - min_

    a = [e - min_ for e in a]
    a = [e / d for e in a]

    return a

def compress(values, extrema):
    #identifies consecutive mins/maxs and takes the more extreme of the two

    prev_ext = None
    last_index = 0

    for i, ext in enumerate(extrema):

        if ext == NEITHER:
            continue

        if prev_ext is None:
            prev_ext = ext
            last_index = i
            continue

        cc = values[i]
        pc = values[last_index]

        if ext == prev_ext == MAX:
            if cc >= pc:
                extrema[last_index] = NEITHER
            else:
                extrema[i] = NEITHER

        if ext == prev_ext == MIN:
            if cc <= pc:
                extrema[last_index] = NEITHER
            else:
                extrema[i] = NEITHER

        if ext != NEITHER:
            last_index = i

        prev_ext = ext

    return extrema

def label(values, C=.4):
    #C is the amount that must change between two points for those points to
    #be considered extremes

    extrema = [NEITHER]

    prev = values[0]
    for curr in values[1:]:
        delta = abs(prev - curr)
        if curr > prev and delta > C:
            extrema.append(MAX)
        elif curr < prev and delta > C:
            extrema.append(MIN)
        else:
            extrema.append(NEITHER)
        prev = curr

    oldextrema = list(extrema)
    extrema = compress(values, extrema)

    while oldextrema != extrema:
        oldextrema = list(extrema)
        extrema = compress(values, extrema)

    #min_indicies = [i for i, e in enumerate(extrema) if e == MIN]
    #max_indicies = [i for i, e in enumerate(extrema) if e == MAX]

    return extrema


if __name__ == "__main__":

    values = [294.82, 294.85, 294.85, 294.83, 294.67, 294.77, 295.71,
              296.31, 296.07, 295.38, 295.83, 296.14, 296.2, 296.35,
              296.07, 296.35, 296.83, 296.9, 296.41, 296.49, 296.43,
              295.77, 295.75, 296.04, 296.12, 296.09, 296.16, 296.1,
              296.32, 296.24, 296.3, 296.5, 296.22, 296.16, 296.13,
              296.07, 296.09, 296.04, 296.29, 296.32, 296.31, 296.35,
              296.43, 296.6, 296.58, 296.4, 296.38, 296.6, 296.56,
              296.63, 296.72, 296.65, 296.69, 296.59, 296.56, 296.63,
              296.74, 296.75, 296.91, 296.81, 296.71, 296.78, 296.65,
              296.66, 296.71, 296.73, 296.89, 296.98, 297.19, 297.09,
              297.01, 296.95, 296.92, 297.0, 296.41, 296.39, 296.05,
              295.68, 295.11, 295.19, 295.3, 295.64, 295.53, 295.36,
              295.86, 295.75, 295.63, 295.65, 295.7, 295.61, 295.57,
              295.52, 295.54, 295.5, 295.44, 295.44, 295.82, 295.85,
              295.86, 296.09, 295.75, 295.41, 295.8, 296.2, 295.66,
              293.49, 293.4, 293.58, 294.37, 294.16, 295.13, 295.58,
              295.34, 295.35, 295.78, 295.87, 296.03, 296.32, 296.87,
              296.9, 296.87, 297.3, 296.98, 297.0, 296.87, 297.11,
              296.97, 297.1, 296.78, 296.72, 296.95, 297.04, 297.11,
              296.94, 296.88, 297.2, 297.04, 296.83, 297.08, 296.96,
              297.07, 296.85, 297.04, 296.93, 296.98, 296.92, 296.96,
              296.97, 296.89, 296.99, 296.94, 296.83, 296.75, 296.89,
              296.93, 296.92, 297.3, 297.12, 297.43]

    extrema = label(values)

    plt.plot(normalize(values))
    plt.plot(extrema)

    plt.show()
```

What I've written seems cumbersome and I'm fairly certain I'm not covering all the edge cases. I'm using `numpy` on this project but I couldn't find anything in numpy that would help me solve this (or more likely I found it but didn't comprehend). Is there a more concise way to write this? If there is anything I can do to clarify please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

- The docstring is the common way of describing functions in Python.
- Especially in Math code, you should articulate a bit more the description of your functions.
- List comprehension can be joined together.
- Assigning `max` is not necessary as you use it only once.
- Some tests make development faster and code easier to read.
- You can return directly, without using an intermediate variable.
- Longer names are preferable: use `delta` instead of d:

Putting it all together:

```
def normalize(array):
    """
    Taking an array of numbers as input,
    numbers become from 0 to 1 while retaining their
    previous ratio.
    Especially useful for graphing purposes.

    >>> normalize(range(5))
    [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
    >>> normalize([5,100,45])
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.42105263157894735]
    """
    min_ = min(array)
    delta = max(array) - min_
    return [(i - min_) / delta for i in array]
```